# can't change JS code color from black in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, tags, phpstorm

I want to change Javascript code color from black to a more light one in my PhpStorm IDE. I could change other code color but not this one. Here is screenshot from my PhpStorm project showing how JS/jQuery looks right now.

[image: jQuery code sample]

I couldnt find any ways to identify what is the name of this variable or function in PhpStorm settings window. There is no black text in it to show what this color belongs to. As you can see below there is no text in black.
[image: editor]

Comment: Go through all available entries above the editor you posted (Bad character, Block comment, ....). Some of those are not represented in the syntax highlighter preview. You should find one, which has a black foreground. If there is no such entry, go to `Color & Fonts → General` and look here for an entry with a black foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
Settings->Editor->Colors&Fonts->Language Defaults click on Identifiers->Default and then select **3 Identifier**

[image: color]